# Rails: How do I use helpers in a separate class in lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm happened to write create one file in lib folder and I want to use TextHelper in that file. How can I make Texthelper available?

Suggestions appreciated,
Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Actually it's not that hard at all.  You can just include the `TextHelper` module from your class.

```
class MyLib
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  def five_things(x)
    pluralize 5, x
  end
end

>> MyLib.new.five_things "dog"
=> "5 dogs"
```

That's from a class I defined in `lib`, and output from a `script/console` session to make sure it all plays nice.

Comment: Strangely this doesn't seem to work if it's a class method, such as `def self.five_things(x)`.  Any idea why?

Comment: Try `MyLib.five_things` instead of `MyLib.new.five_things`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in production mode, any ideas why?

Comment: If you want to include a module into a class and use it in class methods, ie `self.blah`, you need to do `extend SomeModule`.

Answer (score 1):

For those whom the `self` methods don't seem to inherit the functions from helper, this will work:

```
class MyLib

  class << self

    include Path::To::YourHelper

    def test_func(x)
      method_in_helper 5, x
    end

  end

end
```