# How to get url of a restful resource inside lib and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails route url helper (e.g. `item_url(1)`) are accessible in views. However I often need the resource urls outside views. For example I need to use the url to generate shortened urls from goo.gl, and I also need to pass url to Facebook to get the comment counts.

I also have custom helpers which wraps around build-in route url helpers. I want to use these in lib/model as well.

I know generating _url requires the **request** object. So I can accept hardcoding the server domain somewhere in order to generate full url.

How can I get url/ call route url helper from lib or model? I need to access it in the lib class methods as well.

**Similar questions I have read:**

[Rails: How do I use helpers in a separate class in lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896134/rails-how-do-i-use-helpers-in-a-separate-class-in-lib), the solution does not work on lib class' class methods.

[User helper functions in Lib classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178729/user-helper-functions-in-lib-classes),  does not have definite answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to the top or you lib / model

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: @lulalala, because in order to use module's methods on the class level you should use `extend` instead of `include`. You can find a more detailed description, e.g., in [this](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) article.

Comment: @lulalala, btw, including URL helpers into your model might be not the best idea, because in general routing is not something your model should know about. But a 'better' solution will require reconsidering architecture of this part of your app and introducing separate entities that will handle URLs generating.

Comment: As for me I found the need for this separation less convincing. Since it is a restful resource it tends to be unchanged, and will be only way for outside world to reference it. How would you handle shortening urls in this case, if models aren't even created through controllers.

Comment: @KL-7 I just tried `extend Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` but it doesn't work. What could the issue be?